# To display itemname , type and actual price where actual price is price-discount for all all the records

Tags: sql, command

I have 6 columns named itemNo,itemname,taype dateof stock price and discount.I have a question that states  that I have to display itemname , type and actual price where actual price is Price-Discount?

Comment: So I'm getting that you need the most recent price for each item, is that correct? Or can DateOfPrice be future so you need to find the last row that has a date<today? If so I would look at where date<today and not exists(anything later), or use a CTE with row_number() and pick the first row. As this is a homework question that should point you in the right direction without giving the actual answers.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below SQL query to find actual price of item,

```
SELECT itemname, type , price - discount as  ActualPrice from tableName
```

Comment: Think its a question where there can be multiple rows, as it includes a date_of_change column. Not clear from question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select item_name
      ,type
      ,actual_price as price-(price * discount)/100
```